# How do I get the correct sum of a series of random numbers in a 'for loop'

Tags: random

I'm creating a program that creates a 10 play football drive.  I have three Random objects.  One pulls random players and plays.  The second pulls random numbers for positive gains and the third pulls random numbers for a negative play when the quarterback is sacked.

The problem I have is I want to be able to calculate the total yards of the drive after the loop concludes (positive yards - negative yards) and I can't get the numbers to add up correctly.  Any ideas?

public void callPlays() {

```
Random random = new Random();       //plays and players
Random yardsGained = new Random();  //positive plays
Random yardsLost = new Random();    //negative plays

int totalYards=0;
int numberOfYards = 0;
int lossOfYards = 0;

System.out.println("Redskins begin drive on their own 20 yard line");

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
{

    numberOfYards = yardsGained.nextInt(16);
    lossOfYards = yardsLost.nextInt(16);


    String[] passCatchers = new String[6];

    passCatchers[0] = "DeSean Jackson";
    passCatchers[1] = "Pierre Garcon";
    passCatchers[2] = "Jamison Crowder";
    passCatchers[3] = "Jordan Reed";
    passCatchers[4] = "Matt Jones";
    passCatchers[5] = "Chris Thompson";

    int passCatcher = random.nextInt(passCatchers.length); 

    String[] backs = {"Matt Jones", "Chris Thompson"};

    int runningBack = random.nextInt(backs.length);

    String[] plays = new String[7];

    plays[0] = "Pass complete to " + passCatchers[passCatcher]  
    + " for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[1] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the left   
    edge for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[2] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " up the middle for 
    " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[3] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the right  
    edge for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[4] = "Screen pass to " + passCatchers[passCatcher] + " for "  
    + numberOfYards + " yards";

    plays[5] = "Kirk Cousins scrambles for " + numberOfYards + " 
    yards";

    plays[6] = "Kirk Cousins sacked for " + lossOfYards + " yards.";

    int select = random.nextInt(plays.length); 
    System.out.println(plays[select]);


}

totalYards = numberOfYards - lossOfYards;  //does not add up correctly
System.out.println("10 play drive. " + totalYards + " yards.")
```

Comment: I bet gained and lost are returning the same number every time because they will likey have the same seed

Comment: I've been playing with this a little bit.  They both return different numbers.  The problem is both gained and lost are throwing a number during each series of the loop so lost is subtracted from gained every series so at the end of the 10 play drive the math is not correct.  I want 'lost' to only throw a number when plays[6] is called.  Don't know how to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems you are only getting the yardsGained and yardsLost values of last iteration. You need to add/reduce these in every iteration. Try following.

```
public void callPlays() {


 Random random = new Random();       //plays and players
 Random yardsGained = new Random();  //positive plays
 Random yardsLost = new Random();    //negative plays

 int totalYards=0;
 int numberOfYards = 0;
 int lossOfYards = 0;

 System.out.println("Redskins begin drive on their own 20 yard line");

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
 {

    numberOfYards = yardsGained.nextInt(16);
    lossOfYards = yardsLost.nextInt(16);


    String[] passCatchers = new String[6];

    passCatchers[0] = "DeSean Jackson";
    passCatchers[1] = "Pierre Garcon";
    passCatchers[2] = "Jamison Crowder";
    passCatchers[3] = "Jordan Reed";
    passCatchers[4] = "Matt Jones";
    passCatchers[5] = "Chris Thompson";

    int passCatcher = random.nextInt(passCatchers.length); 

    String[] backs = {"Matt Jones", "Chris Thompson"};

    int runningBack = random.nextInt(backs.length);

    String[] plays = new String[7];

    plays[0] = "Pass complete to " + passCatchers[passCatcher]  
    + " for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[1] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the left   
    edge for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[2] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " up the middle for 
    " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[3] = "Handoff to " + backs[runningBack] + " along the right  
    edge for " + numberOfYards + " yards.";

    plays[4] = "Screen pass to " + passCatchers[passCatcher] + " for "  
    + numberOfYards + " yards";

    plays[5] = "Kirk Cousins scrambles for " + numberOfYards + " 
    yards";

    plays[6] = "Kirk Cousins sacked for " + lossOfYards + " yards.";

    int select = random.nextInt(plays.length); 
    System.out.println(plays[select]);

    totalYards += (numberOfYards - lossOfYards);
 }

 System.out.println("10 play drive. " + totalYards + " yards.")
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but it still doesn't work.  What seems to be happening is lossOfYards is throwing a number for each round of the loop so obviously the total yards do not coincide with yards gained and lost on the plays that are called.  What I want is for lossOfYards to only throw a number when plays[6] is chosen.  I don't know how to make that happen.